# Consistency of replicated map across cluster nodes

Tags: replication, hazelcast, distributed-caching

We use a Hazelcast replicated map in our software. We wish to have a check to ensure that the map is consistent across all the nodes in the cluster. One way is to query each and every key on each node and compare the results. But that obviously has performance implications because of the thousands of keys present. So is there a quicker way of doing the same? (Something like a node-wide checksum)

We haven’t written any code for the checks that we intend to do

Comment: What reason do you have to doubt that the framework is capable of meeting their consistency guarantees?  https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/consistency-and-replication/consistency